# Typescript error using useReducer and useEffect

Tags: typescript, redux, react-hooks, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I've created my reducer function, and I've imported it in my `useShowSpell` component and using it in useReducer but I'm not sure what the error means when it says **No overload matches this call**. Here's an image of the error:

[image]

Here's the code for my `useShowSpell` component:

```
import { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import { apiGet } from '../utils';
import { reducer } from './reducers';

export const useShowSpell = (spellId: string) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    spell: null,
    isLoading: true,
    error: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    apiGet(`spells/${spellId}`)
      .then((results) => {
        if (isMounted) {
          dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', spell: results });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (isMounted) {
          dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', error: err.message });
        }
      });

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [spellId]);

  return state;
};
```

And this is what my `reducer` function currently looks like:

```
type SpellState = {
  spell?: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  error?: string;
};

type SpellAction =
  | { type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS'; spell: any }
  | { type: 'FETCH_FAILED'; error: string };

export const reducer = (prevState: SpellState, action: SpellAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS': {
      return { isLoading: false, error: null, spell: action.spell };
    }

    case 'FETCH_FAILED': {
      return { ...prevState, isLoading: false, error: action.error };
    }

    default:
      return prevState;
  }
};
```

I'm also getting a secondary error in `dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', spell: results })` in the `useShowSpell` component where it says **Expected 0 arguments, but got 1** and not quite sure why I'm getting this error as well when I'm using `useEffect`.

Any ideas on why this might be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. The `error` property is optional, which means it should be `undefined` or `string` type. But you assign `null` to the `error` property in the reducer.

Change:

```
case 'FETCH_SUCCESS': {
  return { isLoading: false, error: null, spell: action.spell };
}
```

To:

```
case 'FETCH_SUCCESS': {
  return { isLoading: false, spell: action.spell };
}
```

The `error` property in the initial state passed to `useReducer` should be `undefined`, NOT `null`.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
  spell: null,
  isLoading: true,
  error: undefined,
});
```

2. The action type is `FETCH_FAILED`, NOT `FETCH_FAIL`. So you should modify it to:

```
dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILED', error: err.message });
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/65484084